# Passing Parameters into JavaScript object events using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, checkbox

I know there are a LOT of similar question to this, but I've tried them all to no avail...so thanks for any help.

**WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO:**
I want to pass one-to-many parameters into each checkboxes 'click' event upon registration (see below).

**WHAT WORKS:**
I can register the event WITHOUT any parameters, and the click event raises...but I need to pass-in a reference to the containing JavaScript grid object (for other reasons).

**WHAT FAILS**
I've tried various forms of "this.MutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxHandler = function(grid){}" to no avail.

**ONE IDEA:**
I "think" currying may be the answer, but I don't quite know how to do it well-enough (yet).

**This area instantiates the grid and registers the checkboxes**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    // CLASS
    function CommitImporterGrid() {
        // PROPERTIES
        this.Toaster = new Toaster();
        this.CheckBoxes = new Array();

        // METHODS
        this.RegisterMutuallyExclusiveCheckBox = function(clientId) {

            var checkBox = $j('input:checkbox#' + clientId);

            // HERE: "I need to pass a reference to the grid somehow"
            $j(checkBox).click(this.MutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxHandler);

            this.CheckBoxes.push(checkBox); // Append to array
        }
        this.MutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxHandler = function() {

            // The checkbox events break when I try to add a parameter.
            var myGrid = "I need to retreive the grid reference here somehow";

            if (!$j(this).is(':checked')) { // They clicked on the same checkbox
                this.checked = true;
                return;
            }

            // ...other code...
        }
    }

     // CLASS INSTANCE
     var myGrid = new CommitImporterGrid();

     // DOM EVENT: Document.Ready()
     $j(document).ready(function() {

         // DYNAMIC REGISTRATION
         myGrid.RegisterMutuallyExclusiveCheckBox('chkCommitImporter01');
         myGrid.RegisterMutuallyExclusiveCheckBox('chkCommitImporter02');
     });
-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and pass event data (assuming your grid is the current object):

```
// HERE: "I need to pass a reference to the grid somehow"
checkBox.bind('click', {grid: this}, this.MutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxHandler);
```

*(you don't need to pass `checkbox` to jQuery, it is already a jQuery object)*

and change your method to:

```
 this.MutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxHandler = function(event) {
      var mygrid = event.data.grid;
      //...
 }
```

*(You can can access the event data via `event.data`)*

Comment: @SLaks: Why? It should, otherwise, `this.MutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxHandler` won't work either.

Comment: Inside the handler, `this` will be the DOM element.

Comment: @SLaks: I think inside the handler, `this` **should** refer to the DOM element, otherwise, `!$j(this).is(':checked')` would not make sense.

Comment: Felix is correct: within the handler "this" did indeed referred to the (checkbox) element.  So the "is checked" logic is working.  As for the even.data solution...it works like a CHAMP.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an anonymous function that calls your handler with your parameters, like this:

```
this.RegisterMutuallyExclusiveCheckBox = function(clientId) {
    var self = this;

    var checkBox = $j('input:checkbox#' + clientId);

    $j(checkBox).click(function() {
        self.MutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxHandler(parameters);
    });

    this.CheckBoxes.push(checkBox); // Append to array
};
```

Inside the event handler, `this` refers to the element that triggered the event.
I therefore use a separate `self` variable instead.